# Theme Development in Octopress

Tags: octopress

Octopress is a great blogging engine; however, I seem to have a lot of trouble finding how to create a new theme in Octopress.

The official guide I found (http://octopress.org/docs/theme/) only limits to how to modify the official theme, and doesn't really detail the syntax such as

```
{% assign index = true %}
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
{% assign content = post.content %}
```

nor the directory structures. Other theme creators (http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2012/10/31/the-making-of-an-octopress-theme/) have simply done this by looking at the default theme, which is the path I might take.

But before I embark on this strenuous process, I want to know if there is some kind of guide to creating Octopress themes that I might have missed.

Thank you,

Comment: I has the same issue as you, and after I learned more I wrote [a short guide](http://chymeric.eu/blog/2013/12/30/octopress-theme/) to octopress theming. It is by no means exhaustive, but it teaches you a bit about the octopress structure and that you can always use ```grep``` to find out more about your individual use case.

Comment: thanks! I ended up writing my own theme also by looking at another theme as an example: https://github.com/rickypai/octopai

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Octopress themes are in reality just [Jekyll templates](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) (Octopress is a wrapper around Jekyll that provides nice extras) which use the [Liquid templating engine](http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid).

You can learn more about Jekyll (including the [directory structure](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/)) from the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/).
You can learn more about [Liquid tags](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers) on their [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/).

Comment: Thanks Sam, this is hugely helpful.  Being unfamiliar with Jekyll (but familiar with Octopress) I was under the impression that Octopress had invented that directory structure and methods of naming.  No longer! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could look at other people theme code on github: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/wiki/3rd-Party-Octopress-Themes